# Вложенные списки в Android

Tags: android, listview, android-layout, android-customview

Будет ExpandableListView, примерно 4х4. Layout каждого из его рядов - виджет, состоящий из 12 горизонтально расположенных квадратиков, каждый из которых закрашен в определенный цвет. По клику на внешний ряд некоторые из квадратиков будут менять окраску.
Как это проще сделать - ListView/RecyclerView/CustomView/CustomLayout ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: объясните доступнее

Comment: На рисунке - 4 ряда ListView, внутри которых - горизонтально расположенные квадратики. Вопрос в том, как нарисовать эти квадратики

Comment: если их всегда одинаковое кол-во, то просто 12 `View`. Можете их циклом добавить программно, например. Т. к. они все одновременно видны, смысла в ListView/RecyclerView нет

Comment: Спасибо. Так и сделаю

Comment: я бы воспользовался GridView, так как все четко разбивается на строки и столбцы и в дальнейшей логике обработки проще чем ExpandableListView.